vercel ai - onFinish function don't run when AI response complete?
I am using ai/react library in NextJS project:
import {useCompletion} from "ai/react";
and this is my completion function code:
    const {
        input,
        isLoading,
        handleInputChange,
        handleSubmit,
        setInput
    } = useCompletion({
        api: `/api/chat/${companion.id}`,
        onResponse: (response) => {
          console.log("C2");
        },
        onFinish(_prompt, completion) {
            console.log("C1");
            const systemMessage: ChatMessageProps = {
                role: 'system',
                content: completion,
            }

            setMessages((current) => [...current, systemMessage]);
            setInput('');

            router.refresh();
        }
    });

as the code above works properly and AI response is generated and is runs onResponse function but it don't run onFinish function, I don't know why as I console log in each function and it just print C2 is in console.
Can someone point out how to solve this?
